Как обратится к pygame Group?
Вот проба кода:
try:
    import pygame
except ImportError:
    import os
    os.system("pip install pygame")
    import pygame

import random

pygame.init()

white = (254, 254, 254)   # цвета тут  --> COLORS <--
yellow = (253, 255, 102)
black = (1, 1, 1)
gray = (120, 120, 120)
dark = (100, 100, 100)
brown = (109, 100, 90)
red = (252, 39, 39)
green = (10, 180, 10)
lightblue = (80, 150, 255)
blue = (53, 125, 231)
orange = (255, 100, 130)

dis_width = 800
dis_height = 600

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("Textures/Logo.ico"))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mine game')

dis.fill(gray)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

texture = pygame.image.load('Textures/EXPbattery_mine.png')
texture2 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Copper_block_mine.png')
texture3 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Copper_ore_mine.png')
texture4 = pygame.image.load('Textures/DirtTitle_mine.png')
texture5 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Iron_ore_mine.png')
texture6 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Leadmetall_mine.png')
texture7 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Minerr_mine.png')

block = 48
rect = pygame.Rect(48, 48, 48, 48)  # ore deposit
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()


def coll(spd, ore):
    if spd[0] > ore.X and spd[0] < ore.X + block and spd[1] > ore.Y and spd[1] < ore.Y + block:
        return 1


def rnd():
    f = round(random.randrange(block, dis_height - block * 2) / 10.0) * 10.0
    return f


class ore_deposit(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = texture.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(X + 24, Y + 24))
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y


def gameloop():
    ore = ore_deposit(rnd(), rnd())
    blocks.add(ore_deposit(rnd(), rnd()), ore_deposit(rnd(), rnd()))
    game = True

    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():        # события и управление
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = False

        dis.fill(gray)
        blocks.draw(dis)
        spd = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i in range(0, len(blocks)):   # как сделать, чтобы он проверял каждый
            if (coll(spd, blocks)) == 1:  # элемент из группы blocks?
                dis.fill(red)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)


gameloop()    

